# MVC read value from textboxfor with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor

I think it´s pretty simple, but i don´t get it.
I want to read the value from an input control with jquery.

I have this line:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Email" })
```

If I try to read the value with this line, i will get back an empty string

```
$("#Email").val()
```

If i try something like this, it works

```
$("#Email").keyup(function () {
        alert(this.value);
    });
```

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks

Edit:
Html

```
<input name="Email" id="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email" data-val-required="field is required" data-val="true" value=""/>
```

Comment: `$("#Email").val();` should work. Can you show your html?

Comment: You are getting an empty string because the input it empty.. On keyup it shows a value because it out puts the key that you have pressed

Comment: did you wrap your code within document.ready() event?

Comment: I´ve updated my first post with the html. @highwingers Yes I wraped my code in document.ready() $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").click(function () {
            alert($("#Email").val());
        });
    });

Comment: Also, that part `data-val-required="Das Feld "Email Adresse" ist erforderlich."` seems to be breaking the html (because of the inner double quotes). Replace it with this: `data-val-required='Das Feld "Email Adresse" ist erforderlich.'`

Comment: @Felipe Castro I´ve updated the data-val-required part, but it dont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add a reference to jQuery?

I tested in JSFiddle and it works: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VyDkf/)

HTML:

```
<input name="Email" id="Email" type="text" placeholder="Email" data-val-required="field is required" data-val="true" value=""/>
<input type="button" id="test" value="test" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () {
        alert($("#Email").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @glatrou now I´ve found my issue. Because the Email field is displayed in a dialog, I forgot that another email field with the same id is still in the background form. I changed the id of one field and now it works. Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

view:

```
    <input type="button" id="test" value="test" />
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "Email" , @id="EmailTxt"})
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () {
        alert($("#EmailTxt").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@id="EmailTxt"
```

we can write

```
id="EmailTxt"
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "Email" , id="EmailTxt"}).
```